# Load multiple records from multiple files into mysql table

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm trying to load different data, from different files, into multiple columns in MySQL. I'm not a big database guy, so maybe I have my data structured wrong. :)

Here's how I have it set up:

```
DATABASE: mydb
TABLE:    aixserver1
COLUMNS:  os, hostname, num_users, num_groups, pkg_epoch

shown from mysql:

+---------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| cur_timestamp | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| pkg_epoch     | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| os            | char(5)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| hostname      | char(40)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| num_users     | int(10)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| num_groups    | int(10)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+---------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

So basically I want to populate pkg_epoch, os, hostname, num_users and num_groups into the database. The data I want to load is inside 5 flat files on the server. I'm using ruby to load the data.

My question is how do I load all these values from those files into my table at once. If I do my inserts one at a time, then the other records become NULL. I.E, I load data into just the hostname column, and all the other columns become NULL for that row.

What am I missing? :)

Comment: what does your insert query look like? show me the ruby code you are using to get the file data and to insert into the db

Comment: `insert into test(pkg_epoch, os, hostname, num_users, num_groups) VALUES('324234236', 'linux', 'testos', '51', '90');`

Comment: That insert works.. but I'm going to be loading the values from a file. I just typed that into the mysql command prompt. Plus.. this is just five to start. I could have 20-50 things to insert when I'm done with this. So I don't think just parsing the data from a file, and doing one giant insert statement will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this a couple ways but the trick is to use a variable placeholder.  Here is an example if you used the database's LOAD DATA function:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/PATH/TO/FILE' IGNORE INTO TABLE tableName FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES  
TERMINATED BY '\r' (@skip, @skip, @skip, login_name, pwd, @skip, @skip, @skip, @skip, @skip, first_name, last_name);
```

You see I just set a variable @skip or @anything for the fields I don't want to include in the database and name the columns that I do want.

---

I can get you halfway there with this but am uncertain best approach if you build your own loader with Ruby.  I would suggest you retrieve the file and let MySQL import using LOAD DATA as it'll be very performant and you can use trick above.

Comment: note my example assumes the file is tab-delimited "\t" but you might have fixed width or comma delimit so you'll adjust accordingly.  Also some character sets you may need to delimit rows with "\r\n" but "\r" should work.

Comment: Hmm I guess I don't understand. The file I'm trying to load only has ONE value. So I have 5 files with 5 values for 5 different columns.

One file called "os" only has one line in the file called 'AIX'. Another file called 'hostname' only has one line in the file called 'aixtest'. I'm trying to load both files into one row in one table.

Comment: ah, I see what you're saying.  somehow I was reading the opposite where the file included more columns that what you need.  there are a variety of "geeky" ways you could do that with unix commands to first merge/delimit the files but that assumes every row matches.  If you only have one value in each file, are you assuming that every row matches the row in other files exactly?

Comment: Yep. Basically what I'm doing is tracking the number of users, number of groups, hostname and os from a server. I'm gathering the data via shell scripts and scping it to my mysql server. They're all in different files. So I'm guessing there is no easy way to do it.. I should merge the files and load it like that. The only other idea I had was to load each file into a temporary table, and then JOIN them so all the values show up in the same row in my main table. I know the data is correct, I just need them all to show up in the same row.

Comment: well your database definition makes it a challenge too because you see that you have non null fields in there so you cannot just insert a row with one value, without some nulls for others.  I think your best bet is a script first to merge files before loading in DB.  I wish I could help you there but I know enough Linux to be dangerous.  A crafty shell script with SED command and I bet you could pull it off, then use my example for LOAD DATA (without the @skip most likely if you build the file to your spec).

Comment: So if I make them not-null I insert a row with one value? I just want to make sure the timestamps all line up. I.E if I insert data in to the OS column, and then a seperate insert for the num_users, they'll share the same increment timestamp

Comment: what you can do in your Ruby code is set timestamp, then execute 5 inserts from 5 files.  first insert will create row and get id, and 4 others will update row, and last update you set timestamp.  It's clunky but that would do it.